# How to create rolling percentage for groupby DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the percent change by month for each product.  Here is what I have so far. I have this working for a DataFrame involving a single product. I am stumped on how to get the calculation applied to a result set that contains many products and many months.

Example dataframe:

```
product_desc    activity_month    prod_count
product_a       1/1/2014          53
product_b       1/1/2014          42
product_c       1/1/2014          38
product_a       2/1/2014          26
product_b       2/1/2014          48
product_c       2/1/2014          39
product_a       3/1/2014          41
product_b       3/1/2014          35
product_c       3/1/2014          50
```

What I need to get out is the dataframe with a percentage change by product_desc by month added to it:

```
product_desc    activity_month   prod_count pct_change
product_a       1/1/2014         53 
product_a       2/1/2014         26         0.490566038
product_a       3/1/2014         41         1.576923077
product_b       1/1/2014         42 
product_b       2/1/2014         48         1.142857143
product_b       3/1/2014         35         0.729166667
product_c       1/1/2014         38 
product_c       2/1/2014         39         1.026315789
product_c       3/1/2014         50         1.282051282
```

I can calculate this on a dataframe with a single product_desc with this:

```
df['change_rate1'] = df['prod_count'].shift(-1)/df['prod_count']
df['pct_change'] = df['change_rate1'].shift(1)
df = df.drop('change_rate1',1)
```

Here is what I am trying now:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['product_desc','activity_month'])

for product_desc, activity_month in df_grouped:
   df['change_rate1'] = df_grouped['prod_count'].shift(-1)/df_grouped['prod_count']
```

However, I get back a 'NotImplementedError' on the last line in the for statement.

Any advice on how to get this calculated correctly is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the leatest version of pandas 0.13.1?

Comment: Yes, this is pandas 0.13.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it looks like within groups, there is one observation per month and you want the percent change from one month to the next. You can do that with a `groupby/apply` by grouping on 'product_desc' and then using the built in `pct_change()` method:

```
>>> df['pct_ch'] = df.groupby('product_desc')['prod_count'].pct_change() + 1
```

Note, I added 1 to the `pct_change()` method because it computes the net percent change. I'll print out a sorted version so it matches your expected output:

```
>>> df.sort('product_desc')

  product_desc activity_month  prod_count    pct_ch
0    product_a     2014-01-01          53       NaN
3    product_a     2014-02-01          26  0.490566
6    product_a     2014-03-01          41  1.576923
1    product_b     2014-01-01          42       NaN
4    product_b     2014-02-01          48  1.142857
7    product_b     2014-03-01          35  0.729167
2    product_c     2014-01-01          38       NaN
5    product_c     2014-02-01          39  1.026316
8    product_c     2014-03-01          50  1.282051
```

On older versions of `pandas` you might have to do:

```
>>> df['pct_ch'] = df.groupby('product_desc')['prod_count'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change() + 1)
```

Or you could use shift as you suggest with a small modification:

```
>>> df['pct_ch'] = df['prod_count'] / df.groupby('product_desc')['prod_count'].shift(1)
>>> df.sort('product_desc')

  product_desc activity_month  prod_count    pct_ch
0    product_a     2014-01-01          53       NaN
3    product_a     2014-02-01          26  0.490566
6    product_a     2014-03-01          41  1.576923
1    product_b     2014-01-01          42       NaN
4    product_b     2014-02-01          48  1.142857
7    product_b     2014-03-01          35  0.729167
2    product_c     2014-01-01          38       NaN
5    product_c     2014-02-01          39  1.026316
8    product_c     2014-03-01          50  1.282051
```

You don't need to refer to `df['prod_count']` within a `groupby`, you're not doing anything to that column.

On older versions of `pandas` you might have to do:

```
>>> df['pct_ch'] = df.groupby('product_desc')['prod_count'].apply(lambda x: x/x.shift(1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. The pct_change function was exactly what I needed. However, when I apply the sort they don't sort the same way. Did you convert the activity_month into dates with strptime first? My results are sorted by product_desc but have the activity_month out of order.

Comment: I did turn the `activity_month` column in to a datetime dtype. You could sort on both to ensure the proper ordering: `df.sort(['product_desc','activity_month'])`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I posted up the similar question here if you want to get another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771165/how-to-sort-by-two-different-dataframe-columns

Comment: This solution doesn't work when the activity_month is not in order. The calculation breaks. I posted a new question here that is following this same example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790415/how-to-groupby-multiple-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-in-pct-change-calculation