# Calculating autocorrelation for each column of data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, autocorrelation

I want to calculate first order autocorrelation in pandas, for each column of my data.

I expect that each of the following code give the same results, but the result are not the same.

Which one should I use?

```
df[df.columns.to_list()].apply(lambda x: x.corr(x.shift()))
```

or

```
df[df.columns.to_list()].apply(lambda x: x.autocorr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second one should be `df[df.columns.to_list()].apply(lambda x: x.autocorr())` as you need the inner parentheses to call the `autocorr` function.

These snippets should give the exact same result, because the implementation of `autocorr` is 1 line of code: `self.corr(self.shift(lag))` which is the same as your first snippet.

Please share your data with a reproducible example if this still isn't working.

As a secondary note- using `df[df.columns.to_list()]` isn't doing anything special since you're not creating a subset of the data so you can simply just do `df.apply` and skip `df[df.columns.to_list()]`

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually, when I added the parentheses now shows same results as method. Why the code still runs without the parentheses?

Comment: The code runs because, in python, functions are objects. So `x.autocorr` is simply getting the function `autocorr` that is attached to the object `x` (a `pd.Series` object). Now this function is also an object itself- and this is what will be returned if you don't add the parentheses. You need the parentheses to `call` the function and make it actually do what you expect it to.

Comment: can you please tell me why in the link below, "in the first answer", `pd.Series.pct_change` is used without parentheses?  and it does not even work when I add the parentheses!!! What am I missing in understanding this concept?    https://stackoverflow.com/a/54322406/14138454

Comment: Yeah, that is a great example of passing a function as an object. Essentially, the function call is delayed so that the `groupby` operation can provide an argument to it. Though this isn't pandas specific, you can read more about [passing a function as an object](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-function-as-an-argument-in-python/)