# Python - Perform calculation on column according to row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate the annual percentage change in GDP for respective countries in a dataset. The dataset is formatted as follows, with each row corresponding to a annual recording for a country:

| Country | Year | LifeExp | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chile | 2000 | 77.3 | 7.79e+10 |
| Chile | 2000 | 77.3 | 7.79e+10 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Zimbabwe | 2014 | 59.2 | 1.59e+10 |
| Zimbabwe | 2015 | 60.7 | 1.63e+10 |

Ideally, I would like to loop over the rows and if the country in that row is the same as the previous row, calculate the percentage change in GDP between the two rows.

Until now, I have had to go through each country individually and append it to a new column `GDP%` myself. I've tried to put the code below into a loop and have the country name as a variable (below: `'Chile'`), but to no avail.

```
gdp_data['GDP%'] = 0
gdp_country = gdp_data[gdp_data['Country'] == 'Chile']
gdp_data['GDP%'] = gdp_country['GDP'].pct_change()
```

Is there a (correct and) more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be similar to [this question about group by and percent change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54322342/pandas-groupby-and-calculate-percentage-change)

You want to sort by country and year first, then group, then apply `.pct_change()`.

Try something akin to:

```py
gdp_data.sort_values(by=['Country', 'Year'], inplace=True, ascending = [True, True])
gdp_data['GDP_Percent_Change'] = gdp_data.groupby('Country')['GDP'].pct_change()
```